# combining jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery

My IDE is complaining about in-efficient use of jQuery selector and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. Thanks

```js
    $('#login2').addClass('inactive');
    $('#login2>input').attr("disabled", 'true');
```

Comment: `$('#login2').addClass('inactive').find("input").attr("disabled","disabled");`?

Comment: Your code is efficient. You should ask how to fix your ugly IDE..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `$('#login2')` to var:

```
var $login = $('#login2');

$login.addClass('inactive');
$login.find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Should also be able to chain, but (to me) can get messy:

```
$login.addClass('inactive').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The inefficiency comes from the fact that you are starting from the top-level of the DOM for both queries when your second query could target the specific subset of the DOM underneath the `#login2` element.

Cache your first query result in a variable with

```
var $login = $('#login2');
```

Then call `.find` for the next query. That way jQuery only has to traverse the smaller subtree to find `input` elements.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has `.prop()` to change element properties and so while using the `.attr()` will work, it is suggested to use `.prop()`:

```
$("#login2>input").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: `prop()` is supported only for jQuery 1.6 and above